# How to route from an <iron-ajax> callback

Tags: ajax, polymer, polymer-2.x

Given a root component in `index.html` (`my-app`) containing `iron-pages`, and an `iron-ajax` call inside one or more of those pages, what is the best way for an `iron-ajax` `on-response` function in a child component to tell `my-app` to change the route? I am using Polymer 2. I see examples relying on links in different components, and calls in the same component, but no `iron-ajax` from one component to its parent.

In `my-app.html` I have an `app-location` and `app-route`, and the `iron-pages`:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
  route="{{route}}"
  pattern="/:page"
  data="{{routeData}}"
  tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

<app-toolbar>...

<iron-pages role="main" selected="[[routeData.page]]" 
    attr-for-selected="name" selected-attribute="visible" 
    fallback-selection="404">
  <my-login name="" route="[[subroute]]"></my-login>
  <my-todos name="my-todos" route="[[subroute]]"></my-todos>
  ...
  <my-404-warning name="404"></my-404-warning>
</iron-pages>
```

The user first sees `my-login`. When the `iron-ajax` in `my-login` call completes, I want to replace `my-login` with `my-todos`. I’ve come up with two approaches so far (see below). Both work--changing the page and updating the URL--but is one necessarily better? Is there a cleaner approach I’ve not found?

The `iron-ajax` on-response handler in `my-login`

```
_handleLogin(e) {
  if (e.detail.response) {
    let loginInfo = e.detail.response;
    if (loginInfo.o_error) {
      console.log('login error: '+loginInfo.o_error);
      // ...
    } else {
      this.dispatch('login', loginInfo); // to polymer-redux store

      // UPDATE PATH, OPTION #1
      var page = this.ownerDocument.body.children[0];
      page.set('route.path', 'server-catalog');

      // UPDATE PATH, OPTION #2
      this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change-route', {
         bubbles: true, composed: true, detail: "my-todos" }));

      // UPDATE PATH, OPTION #3..n
      ???
    }
  } else {
    console.log(e.detail);
  }
}
```

Both options trigger the observer, `_routePageChanged(routeData.page)`, and so the magic proceeds.

Option #1 is straightforward, but involves reaching directly into the parent, my-app.

Option #2 relies on two additions to `my-app`:

```
ready() {
  super.ready();
  // Custom elements polyfill safe way to indicate an element has been upgraded.
  this.removeAttribute('unresolved');
  // listen for custom events
  this.addEventListener('change-route', (e)=>this._onChangeRoute(e));
}

_onChangeRoute(e) {
  this.set('route.path', e.detail);
}
```

Option #2 feels better, but I’m wondering if it’s the cleanest I can do.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to pass `routeData` into `<my-login>` via data binding, and set `routeData.page = "my-todos"` in your `_handleLogin()`

Comment: But `routeData` is not part of `my-login`. The route is in `my-app.html`. `my-login` is the form and the `iron-ajax` for the login call. When the login is successful, isn't it up to `my-app.html` to change the page?

Comment: Can you try to make `routeDate` part of `my-login` by defining a property for it, passing value through data binding, and update the property as option #3?

Comment: I think I don't know enough (yet) about Polymer to understand how adding `routeData` as an attribute of `my-login` in the example above (or another variation) will tell `iron-pages` in `my-app` to set `selected="[[routeData.page]]"`. I'll read through [Data system concepts](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-system) again.

I want `polymer-redux` to manage state (and adapted [Polycast #61](https://github.com/johnthad/polycast61) and [#62](https://github.com/johnthad/polycast62) for Polymer 2). Maybe a store member like `nextPage` could be used for routing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a third way (and one I think I'll use) in the [app-location](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-route/elements/app-location) docs: "`app-location` fires a `location-changed` event on `window` when it updates the location". So,

```
window.history.pushState({}, null, '/new_path');
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('location-changed'));
```